# SpringMVC gets an error "There is already controller bean method" although there is any other methods in the same controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am developing a REST API with Spring MVC.
And it builds successfully, but when I try to deploy it to Tomcat 8.0.57
it gives the following error saying I have already a bean method in that controller. But I dont have any two methods with same names or RequestMethod.

This is the Apache Tomcat Log

```
    29-Nov-2017 18:29:41.796 INFO [http-nio-8087-exec-72] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
29-Nov-2017 18:29:41.844 INFO [http-nio-8087-exec-72] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
29-Nov-2017 18:29:42.783 SEVERE [http-nio-8087-exec-72] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'chatUserController' method 
public java.lang.String org.test.chatapi.controller.ChatUserController.saveUser(org.test.chatapi.model.User)
to {[],methods=[POST]}: There is already 'chatMessageController' bean method
public java.lang.Integer org.test.chatapi.controller.ChatMessageController.saveMessage(org.test.chatapi.model.Message) mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:460)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1586)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor94.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1460)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:906)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:344)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'chatUserController' method 
public java.lang.String org.test.chatapi.controller.ChatUserController.saveUser(org.test.chatapi.model.User)
to {[],methods=[POST]}: There is already 'chatMessageController' bean method
public java.lang.Integer org.test.chatapi.controller.ChatMessageController.saveMessage(org.test.chatapi.model.Message) mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.assertUniqueMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:570)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:534)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:258)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 59 more

29-Nov-2017 18:29:42.789 INFO [http-nio-8087-exec-72]  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root      WebApplicationContext
```

And these are the Controllers.
ChatUserController

```
@RestController
public class ChatUserController {

// Store the Users temporarily
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

// Get all the online users
@RequestMapping(name = "/users/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ArrayList<User> getUsers(){
    users.add(new User("Janith","Hellow worlds"));
    return users;
}

// Save new user / User Login
@RequestMapping(name = "/users/",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@RequestBody User user){
    if(user != null){
        users.add(user);
        return "Successfull Saved";
    }else{
        return "Failed";
    }
}

// Remove the user /  User sign out
@RequestMapping(name = "/users/{uname}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String deleteUser(@PathVariable String uname){
    for(User u:users){
        if(u.getUsername().equals(uname)){
            users.remove(u);
            return "Removed Successfully";
        }
    }
    return "User Not found. Should be already Deleted.";
}
}
```

ChatMessagesController

```
@RestController
public class ChatMessageController {

    ArrayList<Message> messagesList = new ArrayList<>(); 

    @RequestMapping(name = "/messages/{username}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ArrayList<Message> getChat(@PathVariable String username) {

        // create a new list of unread messages
        ArrayList<Message> myMessages = new ArrayList<>();

        // add the unread messages to list
        for (Message m : messagesList) {
            if (m.getReciever().equals(username)) {
                if (!m.isViewed()) {
                    m.setViewed(true);
                    myMessages.add(m);
                }
            }
        }       
        return myMessages;
    }

    @RequestMapping(name = "/messages/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Integer saveMessage(@RequestBody Message message){
        if(message != null){
            message.setViewed(false);
            messagesList.add(message);
            return new Integer(1);
        }else{
            return new Integer(0);
        }
    }
}
```

But this ChatUserController worked fine, I deployed and tested it.
This error is getting after adding the ChatMessageController's second method saveMessage(). And also this same error showed when the first method getChat() was in GET RequestMethod. It was fixed after I changed it to the PUT method.
I am new to Spring MVC Web API, So I appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: This error can occur if you are using maven to build your project the classes are not cleaned out. It happens if you move a class from one package to another . Do a mvn clean before your build

Answer (score 0):

In my case I go to read Spring doc to find some explanation but I finished when found this in RequestMapping interface:

`Note: This annotation can be used both at the class and at the method level. In most cases, at the method level applications will prefer to use one of the HTTP method specific variants @GetMapping, @PostMapping, @PutMapping, @DeleteMapping, or @PatchMapping.`

So I decided also to prefer to use `@GetMapping, @PostMapping, @PutMapping, @DeleteMapping, or @PatchMapping` and it works in my case.

Try to make:

```
@GetMapping("/users/")
public String saveUser(@RequestBody User user){
    //...
}

@DeleteMapping("/users/{uname}")
public String deleteUser(@PathVariable String uname){
    //...
}
```

P.S: also we need use `value` if we need set path:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

`name` its only name, not path